# Datatables paging not showing up

Tags: jquery, datatable

New to datatables and so far have tried every solution I can google.

I have a datatable with the following setup but I cannot get the paging buttons to show up.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table[id^="commissionSummaryTable"]').dataTable({
        dom: 'frtB',

        scrollY: '50vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        ordering: false,

        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                className: 'btn btn-success',
                text: 'Export to Excel',
                //footer: true,
                title: 'Commissions Export'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: No, no errors showing up

Comment: How many records are there in table? Can you create a demo fiddle?

Comment: There are about 7000 records

Comment: At this point, I feel like I have tried every possible option when setting up the table.  A suggestion as to what I can even look at would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change the dom parameter in :

```
dom: "fltip",
```

Comment: OH MY GOD THAT WORKED!!!!!!!

Thank you so much, I have been going crazy on this.  I guess there was one option I didn't check.  

Can you please explain what that does?

Comment: Okay, I see the options here:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

So those set the options at the top.  I'm new to jQuery, I thought that was just a variable.

Man, you made my week.  Thank you again!

Comment: You can set or remove the elements of the dom with the dom parameter in the order as you want.
l for the length menu, f is the filter input, t the table, i is the table info, p is the pagination, r is the processing display element. you can check this for more info https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom